# Invalid type for parameter error when using put_item dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3, aws-glue

I want to write data in dataframe to dynamodb table

```
item = {}
for row in datasource_archived_df_join_repartition.rdd.collect():
    item['x'] = row.x
    item['y'] = row.y
    client.put_item( TableName='tryfail',
    Item=item)
```

but im gettin this error 
Invalid type for parameter Item.x, value: 478.2, type: '<'type 'float''>', valid types: '<'type 'dict''>'
Invalid type for parameter Item.y, value: 696- 18C 12, type: '<'type 'unicode''>', valid types: '<'type 'dict''>'

Comment: Do you know what your Table on DynamoDB expects as the data format? Or better still do you know what your Table ```tryfail``` was created with? e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/getting-started-step-1.html

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but it still comes up high in a search and hasn't been answered properly, so here we go.

When putting an item in a DynamoDB table it must be a dictionary in a particular nested form that indicates to the database engine the data type of the value for each attribute. The form looks like below. The way to think of this is that an AttributeValue is not a bare variable value but a combination of that value and its type. For example, an AttributeValue for the AlbumTitle attribute below is the dict {'S': 'Somewhat Famous'} where the 'S' indicates a string type.

```
response = client.put_item(
    TableName='Music',
    Item={
        'AlbumTitle': { # <-------------- Attribute
            'S': 'Somewhat Famous', # <-- Attribute Value with type string ('S')
        },
        'Artist': {
            'S': 'No One You Know',
        },
        'SongTitle': {
            'S': 'Call Me Today',
        },
        'Year': {
            'N': '2021' # <----------- Note that numeric values are supplied as strings
        }
    }
)
```

In your case (assuming x and y are numbers) you might want something like this:

```
for row in datasource_archived_df_join_repartition.rdd.collect():
    item = {
        'x': {'N': str(row.x)},
        'y': {'N': str(row.y)}
    }
    client.put_item( TableName='tryfail', Item=item)
```

Two things to note here: first, each item corresponds to a row, so if you are putting items in a loop you must instantiate a new one with each iteration. Second, regarding the conversion of the numeric x and y into strings, the DynamoDB docs explain that the reason the AttributeValue dict requires this is "to maximize compatibility across languages and libraries. However, DynamoDB treats them as number type attributes for mathematical operations." For fuller documentation on the type system for DynamoDB take a look at [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html) or read the Boto3 doc [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.put_item) since you are using Python.

Comment: Also note that you can do it your way (put_item with a simple dictionary) if you use the higher-level interface provided by the Table object.  You get the Table object from the Resource object. See "Service Resource" at https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#service-resource

Answer (score 0):

The error message is indicating you are using the wrong type, it looks like you need to be using a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) when assigning values to `item['x']` and `item[y]`. e.g.

```
item['x'] = {'value': row.x}
item['y'] = {'value': row.y}
```

Comment: Now im getting this error Unknown parameter in Item.x: "x", must be one of: S, N, B, SS, NS, BS, M, L, NULL, BOOL

Comment: There's a specific type system for dynamoDB (this is what the S, N etc refer to) so you need to make sure you are conforming to whatever schema what set up for the table. I've put a link in my comment on your question.